# Change bootstrap mobile layout from one column to two column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, opencart

i need to change the layout of mobile version of this site **http://ovocne-destilaty.sk/** from one to two column, i need to have two products in the row instead of one like it is now on mobile, or 400% zoom in chrome.
Whats the best way to do it?

I was trying to do it like this, currently it is like this:

```
.product-block {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I changed the width:

```
.product-block {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
}
```

but it doesnt stack next to each other, its just on the left side, but the width is ok now but i just need it to be two products per row.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're not accounting for the white-space. There are a few ways to get rid of these. Change your html structure to:

```
<div class="product-block"></div><div class="product-block"></div>
```

next to each other, or

```
<div class="product-block"></div><!--
--><div class="product-block"></div>
```

by adding empty comments between blocks.

Make sure you set the css for `.product-block` to `display: inline-block` as well.

There are also other options for instance whereby you set the font-size to 0 to a parent container, then add the proper font-size for the content.